# Google Sheets increment month backwards ArrayFormula

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking to have 1 formula and the result filling across.
Trying use current month and then the next 11 cells to the right show the previous months.

Here is my current formula but it does not count backwards.

=Transpose(ArrayFormula(edate(eomonth(today(),-1)+1,row(A1:indirect("A"&datedif(eomonth(today(),-1)+1,EDATE(eomonth(today(),-1)+1,12),"M"))))))

[Month example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukA3K.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

`=ArrayFormula(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-SEQUENCE(1,12))+1)`

Instead of using `-1` in `EOMONTH`, I just used the negative symbol with a `SEQUENCE` of 1 row and 12 columns in length (with the final two default parameters of that `SEQUENCE` being start at 1 and move by 1).